# Can I enroll an NServiceBus Publish in my own TransactionScope?

Tags: wcf, nservicebus, transactionscope

I have WCF services hosted as http endpoints in IIS. At some points in the handling of command requests to these services, I want to publish an event on NServiceBus to indicate what command was processed. Is it possible for me to do that within a TransactionScope that I create and manage in my code (so that I can include my database interactions in the same transaction)? I would want to be able to publish from the bus within that scope, such that the publication actually goes through if the scope is completed. When I run the following:

```
  using (var scope = new TransactionScope()) {
    bus.Publish(new SomethingHappened { Description = String.Format("{0} logged in at {1}", user.Name, DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()) }).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
  }
```

I find that the message is received by subscribers, even though I did not call `scope.Complete()` on the transaction scope. What, if anything, can I change so that the publish is enrolled in the scope?

Comment: Will this article help?https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/transports/transactions

Comment: @SeanFarmar i referred to this document for my implementation. the bus i'm using is configured to use TransactionScope/Distributed Transactions.

Comment: What transport are you using? (MSMQ, LearningTransport)

Comment: MSMQ. I got an answer from a developer at Particular, which I will post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that in order for the transaction scope to manage the async call, you need to open it with the special option `TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled` like so:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled)) {
  bus.Publish(new SomethingHappened { Description = String.Format("{0} logged in at {1}", user.Name, DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()) }).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Doing that, you get the behavior I was expecting.